# How do I deal with linear terms in an ferromagnetic exchange interaction Hamiltonian?

Tags: condensed-matter, hamiltonian, ferromagnetism, exchange-interaction

I am currently working on deriving the dispersion relation of spin waves in a ferromagnetic monolayer, using the Holstein-Primakoff formalism. Regardless of the specifics, in my derivation I am applying an external magnetic field in the a direction that is not along z, leading to linear terms (in creation/annihilation operators) in the Hamiltonian as below, with j and j+sigma the j-th site connected to its nearest neighbours j+sigma by lattice vector sigma.

[image]

In order to get rid of these, a shift in the operators is used, which can normally be chosen to cancel out the linear terms and adding a constant quadratic in this shift to the quadratic Hamiltonian (without linear terms).

[image]

The resulting Hamiltonian reads

[image]

Now, due to nearest neighbour exchange interactions, the part that should sum to zero reads

[image]

This is where I am stuck.
Does anyone have any insights or ideas on how to tackle this problem? Feel free to dm me if you want to discuss this in-depth.
Thank you for taking the time to read!

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.